# C++03 Order of Memory Deallocation After Main

Tags: memory-management, c++03

I'm using a reference counter wrapper which essentially contains a pointer to an object allocated on the heap.  When the reference count drops to 0, the object is deleted by the wrapper.  The reference is to a thread object which will be running until shutdown.  The object that holds the reference is a static class variable (MyClass).

The reference to the thread won't be destroyed (decrementing the reference count to 0 and destroying the underlying object) until after the MyClass destructor runs, which I believe happens after main.  Do I have any guarantee that the memory for the thread won't be deallocated by the OS before the wrapper attempts to deallocate the object?  Is the behavior specified by the C++ standard or is it left to the OS?

Please note I'm using an old abstraction layer and it's assortment of code libraries.  This is what I'm stuck with.  I can forgo using the reference counter wrapper, which is the usual idiom for threads in this library, but it's easier and safer to manage memory the way it was intended.

Comment: The question can be stated more simply.  Suppose I have memory on the heap that is deallocated by a destructor.  But the destructor is not run until after main.  Can I be sure I'm not trying to free memory the OS has already released?